# How to connect to wireless router when SSID isn't broadcast?

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, ssid

I have a wireless router setup, and I have already successfully connected my laptop to that router wirelessly, when the SSID was broadcast.  But, I decided I don't want to broadcast the SSID, so I turned it off.  Now, using WinXP, I cannot seem to manually connect to that access point using the WinXP UI.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to connect to a wireless network manually if you know the SSID and key.
There's some option in the left pane of the "Wireless Network Connection" window that does this.

Here you go: [How to manually connect to Wireless network not broadcasting SSID](http://www.windowsreference.com/windows-vista/how-to-manually-connect-to-wireless-network-not-broadcasting-ssid/)

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you have to build the profile manually.  Here is a [step-by-step](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/using/networking/setup/adhoc.mspx) for adding to an ad hoc network, but the concept is the same.  You go to connection properties of your wireless NIC -> Wireless Tab and Add the connection.

Answer (score 0):

@medikgt provided an excellent link, but I followed those instructions and still no connection.  Finally, I got frustrated, right clicked on the wireless tray icon with the red X through it, and selected the "Repair" menu item.  And it connected!

So, if you have the connection already manually setup in your list, use "Repair" from the tray icon menu and it'll connect.